# Python open() works at the start, and then starts failing

Tags: python, file, encryption

The following code will work multiple times, but then after some time it starts to fail and say that `open() cannot find the specified path`. When I go and look at the path that file is in the correct spot.

I have tried placing my script in multiple directories and that doesn't seem to do anything.

I am having a hard time reproducing, because when I use the debug mode the code always succeeds. Any suggestions would be extremely helpful, thanks!

Overall flow is:

1. Download files from external site
2. Decrypt those files
3. Once the decryption is complete, I am moving them to an archive directory. This script usually will work the first few runs but then after a while open() doesn't seem to be able to see the newly downloaded file. I have edited the code in my original post to show the downloading sequence.
4. I am using the absolute path when calling open()

the error is thrown at `with open(file_path, 'rb') as efile:`

```py
    try:
        # Open a transport
        transport = paramiko.Transport((hostname,port))
        transport.connect(None, username, password)

        # Connect to the SFTP site  
        sftp = paramiko.SFTPClient.from_transport(transport)
        sftp.chdir(host_path)
        
        # find the files to download
        to_download = sftp.listdir()
        
        # download all the files
        for file in to_download:
            # check if the file is a directory, we don't download directories
            if not stat.S_ISDIR(sftp.lstat(file).st_mode):
                sftp.get(file, destination_path + "\\" + file)
        sftp.close()
        transport.close() 
    except Exception:
        raise

    decrypt_creds = get_credentials(x)
    # grab the key pair to decrypt
    gpg = gnupg.GPG(credentials_path)    
    try:
        # decrypt each file and then move it to the output path
        for f in os.listdir(encrypted_path):
            file_path = os.path.join(encrypted_path, f)
            with open(file_path, 'rb') as efile:
                gpg.decrypt_file(efile, passphrase=password, output=output_path + "\\" + f)
    except FileNotFoundError as e:
        logger.error("The target import files are not found: {error}".format(error=e))
        raise
    except Exception:
        raise
```

Stack trace:

```
  File "C:\Users\user\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\runpy.py", line 289, in run_path
    return _run_module_code(code, init_globals, run_name,
  File "C:\Users\user\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\runpy.py", line 96, in _run_module_code
    _run_code(code, mod_globals, init_globals,
  File "C:\Users\user\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\runpy.py", line 86, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "c:\DecryptAndTransfer\DecryptData.py", line 381, in <module>
    main()
  File "c:\DecryptData\DecryptData.py", line 53, in main
    with open(file_path, 'rb') as efile:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'encrypted/file/path/file.pgp'
```

Comment: Can you post then full traceback?

Comment: Something could be deleting the file between the call to `os.listdir()` and the iteration that tries to use the file.

Comment: hey, give some more info please!

Comment: Hey everyone, sorry for the lack of info. What I am trying to do is this:
1. Download files from external site
2. Decrypt those files
3. Once the decryption is complete, I am moving them to an archive directory.

This script usually will work the first few runs but then after a while open() doesn't seem to be able to see the newly downloaded file. I have edited the code in my original post to show the downloading sequence.

I am using the absolute path when calling open().

Comment: @Barmar could you give more explanation please? I started thinking there was some type of timing issue between downloading and decryption.

Comment: What more can I explain? I don't know what else is going on on your system.

Comment: If you have more information, you should put it in the question, not a comment.

Comment: If the path is currently a relative one, you might want to start out by specifying an absolute path instead, so that the working directory of your program can't effect things in unexpected ways.

Comment: As an aside the first `except Exception; raise` is superfluous. On the topic at hand, the thing that isn't adding up us that the file you're using is the result of `os.listdir(encrypted_path)`, so clearly os thinks the file is there too.

Comment: Are you using multiple threads here?

Comment: @Barmar sorry, I haven't posted on here before, I moved the information to the original post.

Comment: @Blckknght  The path is to a mapped drive, and I am using the absolute path right now, at first I used the relative path but then switched to absolute and still get the same error.

Comment: @Guy I am not using any threading.

Comment: My point is that something outside this script might be deleting the file.

Comment: You should put the `try/except` inside the loop, so you can just skip that one file and continue processing the rest.

Comment: Is the `output_path` different from the `encrypted_path`? I'm wondering if the `gpg.decrypt_file` may be changing files in your directory while your working it

Comment: @fourten I wouldn't say issues, but sort of. `os.path.join` isn't a very intelligent function and it can be troublesome with network paths. But not randomly. That makes this quite strange.

Comment: @Guy yes they are different, I will try and make them the same and then move the file after decryption.

Comment: Well, I only see two options here (if you don't have threads). Either (1) `gpg.decrypt_file` somehow changes files in your target directory, or (2) an external program is deleting files from it. It's pretty easy to check (1) - you can change `gpg.decrypt_file` with `pass` and see if you still get the error. if you don't then it's the cuplrit, if you still do, then you need to find the external process deleting your files

Comment: @Guy I used pass and the error produces, when I go to the directory I can still see the file, I will look into what other process are running

Comment: huh, so it always happens with the same file? If that's the case, it's probably not a different process. Perhaps you don't have permissions to read it?

Comment: @Guy I just ran the program and it didn't fail, but it downloaded the other file, but not the one causing issues. I ran the code again and it downloaded the file that causes issues. Then I went to delete that file to test again, and I actually got a warning saying "Could Not find this item, this is no longer located in path/to/encrypted. Verify the item's location and try again".

Comment: @Guy Something with the paramiko library downloading the files might be the issue. Have you used this library before?

Comment: Again, why do you think this has anything to do with Paramiko? It's not even clear how the Paramiko code snippet is related to the rest of your code. Are you saying that without the Paramiko part, the problem does not happen? I cannot imagine that. We need [mcve]. + `encrypted/file/path` does not look like an absolute path to me.

Comment: Update: it appears I have been able to fix the issue by making the program sleep for 10 seconds between using paramiko to download the files from the FTP site, and decrypting them  I am guessing there was two processes accessing the file, pausing the program must allow the first process to finish before the second